# SQL Server. Pasar filas a columnas

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, pivot

Tengo la siguiente tabla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito crear una consulta para obtener:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado con PIVOT, STUFF, etc, pero no lo consigo. Agradecería vuestra ayuda.

Perdonad, soy nuevo en el portal y aún no domino su empleo.
Intento ampliar algo más los detalles de mi consulta.

La tabla de origen tiene del orden de 20.000 registros.

Para un Id en esta tabla origen, puede haber entre 1 y 4 registros, con valores de L, iguales o diferentes.

El orden en que se encuentran es muy importante. Por ejemplo para Id=1 el registro que deberíamos obtener sería: Id=1, L1=100, L2=200, L3=0, L4=0.

Muchas gracias.

***Solución***

Ya tengo una solución que me sirve para resolver mi problema.

Tengo la tabla **PerfilesBastidor** de unos 20.000 registros, de la que muestro algunos registros:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esta tabla desconozco los diferentes valores de la columna **LPerfil**.
Sé que pueden existir para cada valor de **Id_Config**, entre 1 y 4 registros, iguales o diferentes.

Basándome en la respuesta de **Jachguate**, he creado 2 vistas, la primera con la tabla de partida:

**PerfilesBastidor_L1_L4_A_View** con el código

SELECT     Id_Config, LPerfil, 'L' + cast(row_number() OVER (partition BY Id_Config
ORDER BY 
(SELECT     NULL)) AS varchar) NumFila
FROM PerfilesBastidor

con el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y basándome en ésta, la 2ª vista:

**PerfilesBastidor_L1_L4_View**
con el código:

SELECT    Id_Config, COALESCE (L1, 0) L1, COALESCE (L2, 0) L2, COALESCE (L3, 0) L3, COALESCE (L4, 0) L4
FROM         (SELECT     Id_Config, LPerfil, NumFila
                       FROM          PerfilesBastidor_L1_L4_A_View) p PIVOT (min(LPerfil) FOR NumFila IN (L1, L2, L3, L4)) AS pvt

y el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias a todos por vuestro tiempo.

Comment: Adjunta el codigo que has utliizado, es mucho mas facil que con las imagenes, y asi tenemos una guia de la estructura que manejas

Comment: Y so puedes, cambia las imagenes por texto

Answer (score 2):

Buen día @MEK2005, como dice @Kevin Restrepo es importante que relaciones parte del código que estás usando para darte una mejor solución, sin embargo y con base en tus indicaciones debería bastar con un `PIVOT` para lograr tu objetivo, a continuación te muestro la estructura del `PIVOT` con base en los datos de tus imagenes:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
        ID,
        L
    FROM
        TABLA
    )
PIVOT (MIN(L) FOR L IN (100 AS L1, 200 AS L2, 300 AS L3))
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer una operación `pivot` normal, pero primero necesitas construir, de alguna forma, los valores `L1`, `L2`, `L3` que luego se *convertirán* en columnas.

Una forma sencilla de hacer esto es con un CTE. Te explico mi solución:

- El CTE `Datos` simula tu tabla original y contiene los datos de tu ejemplo.
- En el CTE `BaseNumFila` voy numerando las *filas* según se van obteniendo, reiniciando el contador a 1 para cada nuevo `id`. A este número le concateno el prefijo `L`. De tal manera que tendré los valores `L1`, `L2`, `L3` en la columna NumFila
- Hago un `pivot` para la columna `NumFila`, utilizando la función `min()` para *cubrir* el requisito de obtener un agregado. Como sabemos que habrá una única fila para cada valor, podríamos igualmente utilizar `max()` o incluso `avg()`.
- En el `select` del pivot, he utilizado la función `coalesce()` para obtener un cero en las columnas que traigan `null` (por ejemplo, cuando el *id* no tiene fila `L3`, como el *id* `1`)

El Código de la solución queda, entonces, así:

```
with 
Datos as (
          select 1 id, 100 L
union all select 1, 200
union all select 2, 100
union all select 3, 300
union all select 3, 200
union all select 3, 100
)
,
BaseNumFila as (
select   id
       , L
       , 'L' + cast(row_number() over (partition by id order by (select null)) as varchar) NumFila
  from Datos
)
select   id
       , coalesce(L1, 0) L1
       , coalesce(L2, 0) L2
       , coalesce(L3, 0) L3
  from (select id, L, NumFila
          from BaseNumFila) p
 pivot (min(L) for NumFila in (L1, L2, L3)) as pvt
```

Lo cual produce el siguiente resultado:

```
id          L1          L2          L3
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           200         100         0
2           100         0           0
3           200         100         300

(3 rows affected)
```

Answer (score -2):

en versiones nuevas agregaron la funcion PIVOT buenisima, pero si por alguna razon tienes una anterior revisa el link siguiente:

"https://www.sqlshack.com/es/multiples-opciones-para-transponer-filas-en-columnas/"

Comment: Este es tu segundo aporte que fue marcado como de baja calidad. Por favor es muy importante que leas el [tour] y tambien [answer]. Tene en cuenta que de seguir asi, el sistema te puede bloquear para responder automaticamente.